# css media queries conflicts in iPhone X and iPhone 6/7/8 plus view

Tags: css

```
/*iphone 6/7/8 plus*/
@media screen 
and (min-width : 414px) 
and (max-width : 736px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
and (orientation: portrait)
{   
  #x-section-1 {
    margin-top: 274px!important; 
  }                
}

/*iphone x*/
@media screen 
and (min-width : 375px)
and (max-width : 812px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
and (orientation: portrait)
 {
  #x-section-1 {
    margin-top: 237px!important;
 }    
}
```

The above is my media query.

Using google dev tools for responsive testing. When I used iPhone X to test, it displayed correctly with the `margin-top` is `237px!important`.

But when I used iPhone 6/7/8 plus to test, the `margin-top` value was still reference to iPhone X's `margin-top` value.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the viewport meta tag in your HTML head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then instead of using max-width / min-width, trying using device-width :

UPDATED CODE:

```
 /* iphone X */
@media only screen and (min-width: 812px) { }


/* iphone 6+, 6s+, 7+, 8+ */
@media only screen and (min-width: 736px) { }
```

Comment: Yes I have that meta tag in my document. I tried using min-device-width and max-device-width but the problem is still there. Any other solution?  Thanks for answering.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using just max-width, leaving out min-width? Because it looks like both media queries are trying to access the same thing

Comment: I tried removing the min-width for both but it is still picking the one for iPhone X. what should I do?

Comment: Ah right my bad remove max-width and only use min-width.

Comment: no luck! it's still getting the iPhoneX for iPhone6.7.8.plus :(

Comment: your UPDATED CODE didn't work either. hmmm... I don't know what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your second media query also matches old iPhones. It says that it is applied whenever screen width it between 375px & 812px, and 414 to 736px are in this range also.

To adapt for the iPhone notch you shouldn't use these media queries and instead use some special CSS for this case, as advised by Webkit developers in [their article](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/).

Your code will look something like this:

```
#x-section-1 {
  margin-top: 274px!important; 
}

@supports(padding: max(0px)) {
    #x-section-1 {
        margin-top: max(237px, env(safe-area-inset-top)) !important;
    }
}
```

And you also need to have `viewport-fit=cover` in your viewport meta tag for that to work.

Comment: I'm confused. What does this
        #x-section-1 {
          margin-top: 274px!important; 
        }
means? it has not inside a media query. what about the media query for the other twos?

Comment: First part means you should write first Css for all devices and then some tweaks for the devices that need it. And if your goal is to adapt to the notch of the iphone X, then you actually need not a media query, but the code that I wrote before. Please read the page from the link for more info on how to adapt for iphone x and why the code is like that.

Comment: hi spadar, could we email you about a small consulting project (really, just an architecture question on SVG)? will delete this comment once you read it. thanks!